# Why i'm getting two different rows for one id even after using GROUP BY (id) clause in JOIN operation?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables named guest and booking respectively.

table guest:

| GuestID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | RAJ |
| 1235 | jack |
| 1236 | mary |

table booking:

| GuestID | totalcharge |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 30000 |
| 1235 | 30000 |
| 1236 | 32000 |
| 1234 | 25000 |
| 1235 | 48000 |

I want to select rows with maximum value of totalcharge.
So,When I execute the following query:

```
SELECT guestID, MAX(totalcharge) FROM booking GROUP BY guestID;
```

I get the output as expected i.e.

[image]

But when i join 2 tables using the following code:

```
SELECT b.guestID, name , totalcharge as MAX_AMOUNT
FROM booking b JOIN guest g ON b.guestID = g.guestID
WHERE totalcharge in (SELECT MAX(totalcharge) FROM booking GROUP BY guestID)
ORDER BY b.guestID;
```

I get the following output(ignore the last names):-

[image]

So my question is Why i get 2 rows for id 1235 with different MAX_AMOUNT? but not for id 1234?

The platform on which i am learning RDBMS uses **ORACLE**.

Comment: This is because you’re filtering on charges, not people. Mr. Gupta and Mr. Martin both have a charge of 30,000, hence the two records.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have a GROUP BY clause in your IN subquery.
That evaluates to true for every guestid in booking.

```
WHERE totalcharge in (SELECT MAX(totalcharge) FROM booking GROUP BY guestID)
```

You can see that RAJ GUPTA has the same totalcharge as that of JACKMARTIN and therefore the JACKMARTIN appears twice. (once for max(totalcharge)=48000 and once for max(totalchange)=30000)

In order to get once value, you would do as follows

```
SELECT b.guestID, name , totalcharge as MAX_AMOUNT
  FROM booking b 
  JOIN guest g ON b.guestID = g.guestID
 WHERE totalcharge in (SELECT MAX(b1.totalcharge) 
                         FROM booking b1
                        WHERE b1.guestid=b.guestID
                      )
ORDER BY b.guestID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding why you dropped the max() function and the group by from the second query.  The reason you have repeated rows is that you are not Grouping them in the second query, instead you are relying on a complex filtering scheme to only keep the largest value.

Do what you were doing for your first query in your second query:

```
Select g.guestid,g.name,max(b.totalcharge) as biggest
From booking b JOIN guest g On b.guestid=g.guestid
Group by g.guestid,g.name
Order by g.guestid
```